# Find $N$ When the product of $x_1,x_2,...,x_6$ can be expressed as $2^N$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> For $i=1$ to $6$, let $\log_a(\log_b(\log_cx_i))=0$, where a, b, and c represent every possible different arangement of $2,4,$ and $8$. The product $x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6$ can be expressed in the form of $2^N$. Find $N$.

I have been given the answer which is $N=50$.

I cannot figure out how to solve it myself however, is there a combinatorial approach to this or is it all algebra or calculous? I just need a push in the right direction, and I am tagging with combinatorics tag but feel free to change it if that will not fit.:)

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
&\log_a(\log_b(\log_cx_i))=0\\[3pt]
\implies\; &\log_b(\log_cx_i)=1\\[3pt]
\implies\; &\log_cx_i=b\\[3pt]
\implies\; &x_i=b^c\\[3pt]
\end{align*}

so now you want the product of the numbers $b^c$ for the $6$ permutations of

$$(a,b,c)=(2,4,8) = (2^1,2^2,2^3)$$

which can be worked out explicitly.

The product is $2^{50}$.